# Is it possible to define distinct permissions per subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, permissions

In SharePoint 2013, I want to create several subsites on-demand and then associate users that will manage permissions in some of the subsites.

Is this possible? Distinct permissions per subsite?

Example:

User A can manage subsite 1 and 2, but user B can manage only subsite 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can. You have to manage permission on each subsite.

- Break the Inheritance on Subsite.
- Remove every body from the permissions
- Now add the only person which you want to give permission.

Read this for more information about Permission Inheritance.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/what-is-permissions-inheritance-HA102772762.aspx